# How to copy and rename files in c# windows form app?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to copy a folder on the server and all the files in it into the c disk. If there is the same folder in disk c, I would like to change the name of the folder in disk c to copy the folder on the server to disk c.

```
            string localFile = @"C:\42Apps";
            string sourceFile = @"\\10.10.97.121\pckasabatch\42Apps";

            bool dizinverisi = Directory.Exists(localFile);
            if (localFile != null && localFile.Length >0)
            {
                int i = 0;

               Directory.Move(@"C:\42Apps", "42Apps(old" +i++ +")");
               //File.Move(sourceFile , localFile);  // second method
            }

            else { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like that :

```
string localDirectory = @"C:\"; // no need to get the folder name as it will be the same than the source one
string sourceDirectory = @"\\10.10.97.121\pckasabatch\42Apps";
string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(sourceDirectory); // getting only the name of the folder

string tempDirPath = Path.Combine(localDirectory, directoryName); // creating a temp variable which will be used to check if the folder exists
string dirPath = tempDirPath; // saving for the renaming
string tempDirName = directoryName;

int inc = 0;
// we create a loop to check the first non existing folder name
While(Directory.Exists(tempDirPath))
{
    tempDirName = $"{directoryName}(old{i})";
    tempDirPath = Path.Combine(localDirectory, directoryName);
    i++;
}

if (inc != 0) // if the folder has to be renames
{
    Directory.Move(dirPath, tempDirPath);
}

Directory.Move(sourceDirectory, dirPath);
```

Just for your information, in your code, you create a boolean `dizinverisi` that you forget to use. 
Moreover, don't do `if (localFile != null && localFile.Length >0)` but use `if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(localFile))` instead and maybe add your boolean in the condition after that if you expect the path to be from an incertain input.
This condition could be put at the start of my code with a return if the file doesn't exists. 
Maybe you should test the destination folder too to be sure that it exists